# Boundedness of coupled recursions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is $\theta_n,w_n, n\geq 0$ defined in the following bounded,

$\theta_{n+1} = \theta_n + a(n)\left[\theta_n + w_n\right]$

$w_{n+1} = w_n + b(n)\left[\theta_n + w_n\right]$

$\theta_0, w_0 \neq 0, \sum a(n)=\sum b(n) = \infty, \sum a(n)^2 < \infty, \sum b(n)^2 < \infty$,
$\frac{a(n)}{b(n)} \to 0$

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no. Let $a(n)=\frac1{n+1},b(n)=\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2/3}}$. Then $a(n),b(n)$ satisfy the conditions. Clearly from the first recursion, one has
$$ \theta_{n+1}>\theta_n+\frac{1}{n+1}\theta_n=\frac{n+2}{n+1}\theta_n $$
Thus
$$ \theta_{n}>\frac{n+1}{n}\theta_{n-1}>\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{n}{n-1}\theta_{n-2}>\cdots>\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{n}{n-1}\cdots\frac{3}{2}\frac{2}{1}\theta_1=(n+1)\theta_1 $$
which implies
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\theta_n=\infty. $$
Similarly, from the second recursion, one has
$$ \omega_{n+1}>\omega_n+\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2/3}}\omega_n>1+\frac{1}{n+1}\omega_n=\frac{n+2}{n+1}\omega_n. $$
From this, one has
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\omega_n=\infty. $$

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that $\frac{a(n)}{b(n)} \to 0$

Comment: @Anonymous, see the update.